# Upload file : File Selector style

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, fileupload, lightning-file-upload

[image]

Is there a method to delete the Or drop Files and change the Upload Files with Upload Picture ?

```
 <lightning-layout-item style="width:35%"> 
                    <lightning-spinner if:true={isLoading} alternative-text="Loading" size="small">
                    </lightning-spinner>
                    <div class="slds-m-around_small styleUpload">

                        <lightning-file-upload 
                        name="fileUploader"
                        accept={acceptedFormats}
                        record-id={recordId}
                        onuploadfinished={handleUploadFinished}
                        onchange={saveFile}
                        disabled={disableImport}
                        >
                    </lightning-file-upload>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-m-around_small">
                        <template if:true={fileName}>
                                {fileName} &nbsp; &nbsp; 
                        </template>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                   


                    <template if:true={imageurl}>
                                    <img src={imageurl} style="height: 130px; width: -10px;"/>
                    </template>
                </div>
                       <!--<div class="slds-m-around_small">
                            <lightning-button variant="success" label="Upload" title="Upload" onclick={saveFile}></lightning-button>

                    </div>--> 
                </lightning-layout-item>
```

Comment: what do you mean changed the Upload files with the upload pictures?

Comment: @glls , i mean the text of the button

Comment: replace the button text with the file(s) image(s)? if this is the case, no, there is no way to do this using the component

Comment: @glls i want to replace the text of the button upload file with upload picture and delete the text drop file , is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I want to replace the text of the button upload file with upload picture and delete the text drop file**

No, this is not possible with the component, you would have to code your own for it to behave this way.

You can replace it with an [html input of type file](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_file.asp) component in order to achieve the desired behavior. This will obviously require extra work. Most of the DOM can be found under [the file upload SLDS blueprints](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/file-selector/), for you to achieve a similar look and feel

Comment: thank you for this information

Comment: I wish there was an easier way =P